# Access log shows post requests 404 on pages without any form

Tags: apache

I am experiencing strange 404 access logs. The log is full of post requests with 404 error (pages does not exist on my site). However the request is POST instead of GET. How is this even possible? How can someone do a POST request on page without any form? Thank you for explanation.

Comment: People can make any kind of HTTP request they want to.  Not having a `<form>` tag does not magically prevent people from sending the same kind of request that such a form would make.

Comment: so there is nothing to worry about then?